# Group Collision in python not working

Tags: pygame

Before I get recommended to another question on here, I already checked it out, it didnt help me sadly ;-;.  Soz i started making a game in pygame, loosely following a video and im trying to use groupcollide to check the collide of a bullet and a mob, but for some reason the mobs wont disappear or detect after being hit, can anyone take a look and help me?

```
import pygame, random, os

width = 400
height = 600
fps = 60

# usefule images
rocket_img = pygame.image.load("rocket_ship.png")
astroid_img = pygame.image.load("astroid.png")
nebulous  = pygame.image.load("nebulous.jpg")

# usefull colors RGB
black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
green = (0, 255, 0)
red = (255, 0, 0)
yellow = (255, 255, 0)

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    # player
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = rocket_img
        self.image.set_colorkey(black)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (width / 2, height - 80)
        self.speedx = 0
    def update(self):
        self.speedx = 0
        keystate = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keystate[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.speedx = -5
        if keystate[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.speedx = 5
        self.rect.x += self.speedx
        if self.rect.right > width:
            self.rect.right = width
        elif self.rect.left < 0:
            self.rect.left = 0
    def shoot(self):
        bullet = Bullets(self.rect.centerx, self.rect.top)
        all_sprites.add(bullet)
        bullets.add(bullets)

class Mob(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((30, 50))
        self.image.fill(red)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = random.randrange(width - self.rect.width)
        self.rect.y = random.randrange(-100, -40)
        self.speedy = random.randrange(1, 8)
        self.speedx = random.randrange(-3, 3)
    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += self.speedx
        self.rect.y += self.speedy
        if self.rect.top > height +10 or self.rect.left < -25 or self.rect.right > width + 20:
            self.rect.x = random.randrange(width -self.rect.width)
            self.rect.y = random.randrange(-100, -40)
            self.speedy = random.randrange(1, 8)

class Bullets(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x , y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((10, 20))
        self.image.fill(yellow)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.bottom = y
        self.rect.centerx = x
        self.speedy = -10
    def update(self):
        self.rect.y += self.speedy
        if self.rect.bottom < 0:
            self.kill()

# starts our pygame
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height)) # things to run the game
pygame.display.set_caption("PyGame Shmup!")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()


all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
bullets = pygame.sprite.Group()
mobs = pygame.sprite.Group()
player = Player()
all_sprites.add(player)
for i in range(8):
    m = Mob()
    all_sprites.add(m)
    mobs.add(m)


running = True
while running:

    clock.tick(fps)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                player.shoot()

    # update
    all_sprites.update()

    # check or collisions
    hits = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(mobs, bullets, True, True)
    if hits:
        pygame.quit()

    for hits in hits:
        m = Mob()
        all_sprites.add(m)
        mobs.add(m)
    hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, mobs, False)
    if hits:
        running = False
        pygame.quit()   

    # render
    screen.blit(nebulous, (0, 0))
    all_sprites.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't really test your code, since I don't have your images, but I think I see the problem:

When you spawn the bullet you have:

`bullets.add(bullets)`

`bullets` is the *group* and `bullet` is the bullet you just spawned.  I think you meant:

`bullets.add(bullet)`

I also see two other problems here:

```
hits = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(mobs, bullets, True, True)
if hits:
    pygame.quit()

for hits in hits:
    m = Mob()
    all_sprites.add(m)
    mobs.add(m)
```

`hits` will be your list of collisions.  First, you're saying that if `hits` is not empty, quit the game.  Do you really want the game to quit if a bullet hits a mob?

Second, `for hits in hits` doesn't make sense.  I think you meant `for hit in hits` which would loop through the list of hits, calling each one `hit`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, im new to pygame and really wanna learn it.  I had the quit in it just for testing and forgot to remove it.  and yes i always accidentally put an 's' on the end of things, thats it says 'if hits on hits'.  Thanks for your wonderful help!